# How to access formControl when creating a form via formBuilder in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-formbuilder

I have below code

```
ngOnInit() {

  this.contactsService.getContactByAuthId(this.user.id).subscribe(profile => {
    this.profile = profile;
    this.profileForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: [this.profile.name, Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(6), Validators.required])],
      title: [this.profile.title, Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(6), Validators.required])],
      });

    this.profileForm.title.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
        console.log(value);
        });

  });
}
```

I want to subscribe to `valueChanges` of `title`, but I get `Cannot read property 'valueChanges' of undefined` error.

I am able to subscribe to `this.profileForm.valueChanges` but I want to do some kind of debounce and api call when the title is changed.

It seems that if you have `FormControl` you will be able to subscribe to it's changes but since I am using `FormBuilder` syntax, I don't have access to `FormControl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.profileForm.get('title').valueChanges...
```